# InterlockedAdd not modifying buffer

Tags: multithreading, hlsl, interlocked

I have a `RWStructuredBuffer` that I'm writing to with `InterlockedAdd`, and it appears that the value its spitting out for original is correct, but once the shader finishes running the buffer fully resets to `0`. I have a different `InterlockedAdd` that's running properly.

After execution `_labelCount[0]` is the expected value, but `_labelSizeBuffer` is filled entirely with either `-1` or `0`.

```cpp
cbuffer _ : register(b0)
{
    uint __x;
    uint __y;
    uint __z;
    int _filterSize;
}
       
RWTexture2D<int> _clusterIdBuffer : register(u0);

RWStructuredBuffer<int> _labelSizeBuffer : register(u1);

RWStructuredBuffer<int> _labelCount : register(u2);

[NumThreads(__GroupSize__get_X, __GroupSize__get_Y, __GroupSize__get_Z)]
void Execute(uint3 ThreadIds : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    if (ThreadIds.x < __x && ThreadIds.y < __y && ThreadIds.z < __z)
    {
        int og;
        int2 xy = ThreadIds.xy;
        int2 dispatch = int2(__x, __y);
        int i = xy.y * dispatch.x + xy.x;
        int id = _clusterIdBuffer[xy];
        if (id == -1)
        {
            _labelSizeBuffer[i] = -1;
            return;
        }

        InterlockedAdd(_labelSizeBuffer[id], 1, og);
        if (og == _filterSize - 1)
        {
            InterlockedAdd(_labelCount[0], 1);
        }
    }
}
```